# Dojo: Should all objects be stateful?

Tags: dojo

In dojo I find it convenient to make all objects Stateful.  Is this a best practice or an anti-pattern?

Reasons to make all objects stateful:

- Consistent interface to access properties: All properties are accessed via `someObject.get("someProperty")` and `someObject.set("someProperty", someValue)`
- Convenient builtin mixin constructors.  For example it is possible to instanciate an object like this:

.

```
var objectInstance = new ObjectClass({
    someProperty: someValue,
    someOtherProperty: someOtherValue
});
```

Reasons to not always use Stateful:

- Often I don't need the core functionality of Stateful (notification of state changes).
- Stateful may add overhead to my code
- Stateful may imply that there is a reason to watch the properties in my code (when they really shouldn't be watched)

---

There are clearly some times when it makes sense to make an object stateful.  If you need to `watch` a property, then it makes sense to make an object stateful.  The question I am asking is: "Is it reasonable to make all objects stateful to get access to the syntactic sugar that stateful provides?".  Basicly there are two options:

**Option 1**: Make all classes stateful to get access to Syntactic sugar that stateful provides.

**Option 2**: Only make classes stateful whose members *should* be watched.

Answer (score 0):

This is my opinion based on my experience:

It seems you have already answered your question. I would go with option 2 for sure.
Depending on your application size keeping all objects statefull can become a big problem-an antipattern.

1. Developers that will see your code, will think that your beans are meaningfull even if ther are not
2. Memory is not our problem now-most machines have gigabytes or RAM, only problem will come when your application will reach mark phase in GC, because all of your objects will be kept in memory, our RAM  usage will be medium/high (depending on client capabilities), so you could in some cases see freez screen, if for example you will do some high processing.

So use statefull objects only when it is necessary. Remember that all GC like small short lived objects:) Those long lived will only fill old-space in heap.